# Windows 8, Media Player, K-lite 9.9 (Full) Using Pay to function

Tags: windows-8, video, dvd, windows-media-player

I have K-lite installed and I can now view the SRT file Subtitles with the movie in Windows 8 media player.  When I use play to to send the video to my wireless DVD payer the subtitles don't show.  There must be a tweak in the Codec Tweak program that I just don't have set right.  I've read a lot of blogs and I just can't get it to work.  any suggestions would be helpful.  The reason I bought the DVD wireless player so I could show movies on the large Screen.

Comment: 1. Which wireless DVD player? 2. Does the player even support SRT subtitles or only normal DVD [IDX+SUB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139971/whats-the-vobsub-subtitle-format) subtitles?

Comment: I have a Samsung BD-F5000.  Not sure.  Book says under bitstream (re-encoded Dolby D)    Decodes the main feature audio and Bonusview audio stream together into PCM audio and adds Navigation sound effects then re-encodes the PCM audio into Dolby Digital bitstream or PCM

Comment: According to Google, the Samsung F5000 is a TV and not a DVD player. Please report back with the correct model.

Answer (score 1):

With PlayTo, the device (your DVD player) indicates to the PC what types of audio/video streams it supports. Windows uses this information to offer multiple versions of the same file to the device. For example, if the video were a recorded TV show saved as an MPEG-2 TS file with MPEG-2 video and AC-3 audio, Windows would offer that original version of the file, as well as various transcoded versions such as a version with LPCM audio or even a complete transcode of video and audio into WMV or MP4. It's up to the device to choose which version of the file it can play. If it chooses the original version of the file, which has closed captions encoded into the file, Windows merely streams that file. It's up to the device to make those closed captions available to the rendering code for displaying on screen. However, if the device chooses any transcoded version other than the original, the closed captions are lost. DLNA (and other interoperability standards) don't provide any guidance on how to handle converting closed caption data from one file/stream format to another. In fact, most formats don't even support in-band closed captions.

So - the moral to the story is this: if the device chooses to play the original (native) file, and that file has closed captions in-band, Windows will send the file whole and complete to the device. It's a missing feature of the device if those in-band captions can't be displayed. If the device chooses a non-native transcoded version of the file, the closed captions won't be sent.

Hope this helps.
Gabe [MSFT]